# Vertically place & centre floats with AMS classes just like standard classes

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, amsart, vertical-spacing, amsbook

I'm using my own modified version of the `amsbook` class.

Unlike the standard classes, the AMS document classes place floats with `[p]` option at the top of the thereby created separate float page instead of placing them vertically centred.

Here's an example with `amsart` and `table`, and it's the same with the other AMS document classes, or with `figure` as the float.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
    \caption{Table 1}
    Content of Table 1
\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]
    \caption{Table 2}
    Content of Table 2
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Full Page]

Note also how the vertical space between the two tables is too small:

[image: MWE Zoomed In]

- How can I get the floats to be placed centred on the float page with appropriate vertical spacing, effectively reproducing the 'conventional' behaviour from the standard `article` or `book` classes?
- Since I only use the AMS classes for aesthetics and convenience, not because I'm bound to their authoring & typesetting rules, I have the freedom to modify the document class file and am therefore also interested what code in the actual class file needs to be changed to achieve the desired behaviour.

In this context, I'm wondering whether separate `[p]` float pages are even something that the AMS considers as a possibility in their typesetting. A no answer would mean that the unusual alignment and spacing was simply irrelevant — though I could find nothing in the author guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsbook` class has

```
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}% removed "plus 1fil"
\setlength{\@fpsep}{8pt}% removed "plus 2fil"
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

You can countermand this.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt plus 1fil}% reinstated "plus 1fil"
\setlength{\@fpsep}{8pt plus 2fil}% reinstated "plus 2fil"
%\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
    \caption{Table 1}
    Content of Table 1
\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]
    \caption{Table 2}
    Content of Table 2
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Does one need to change the `\@dblfptop` etc. commands, too? Related question, how can I answer such a question myself if I can't find any documentation on things like `\@fptop`? There's no documentation in the class files, so I'm wondering if there are any resources about this. With any other programming language, I'd just look up the docs, but here…

Comment: @Deniz The description is in `source2e.pdf`